# Determine whether a random coordinate (latitude, longitude) is on the particular route

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, openstreetmap

I'm developing a cross platform application with IONIC/CORDOVA. How can I determine whether a random coordinate (latitude, longitude) with 50 meters radius is on the particular route?

Suppose I have a route defined from one area to another area. I need to find out the users of my application who are on that particular route.

What is the best way to implement this task? Google MAPS API or OpenStreetMap?

Regards

Ashikur Rahman

Comment: This java code should be relative easy to translate into javascript and to be adapted to your usecase https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/util/InstructionList.java#L317

Comment: Is it possible to use Java code directly into IONIC/CORDOVA application?

Comment: As I said: you would need to convert this into JavaScript. A bit related to this topic is that graphhopper is written indeed in Java but it can run in the browser via teavm: https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/graphhopper-in-the-browser-teavm-makes-offline-routing-via-openstreetmap-possible-in-javascript/ With this you could do **offline** re-routing in a cordova app I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      route = "E261", // route name
      latlng = "52.3547673,16.8840211"; // lat and lng

xhr.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng, true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var response = JSON.parse(xhr.response).results;
  response.forEach(function(result) {
    if (result.types.indexOf("route") !== -1 && result.formatted_address.indexOf(route) !== -1)
      console.log("route found");
  });
});
xhr.addEventListener("error", function() {
  // handle error
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Comment: But you would need to know the route name. I think the OP wanted to know the distance to the calculated route from A to B. Not sure ...

Comment: @karusell, he could remove the route variable and `result.formatted_address.indexOf(route) !== -1` and it will check only whether given coordinates are near to route or not